# DataBindXY Gives Zeroes for X Values

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, label, mschart

Let's suppose I have a Winforms app with a Dictionary that looks like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, double> ChartCollection = new Dictionary<string, double>();
```

And let's suppose that I populate this dictionary with the number of each type of various foe which I've recently slain:

```
Ninja, 7
Pirate, 10
Space Cowboy, 4
Zombie, 8
Vampire, 7
```

Finally, let's suppose I bind a chart to this data like so:

```
chtAgentVersions.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(ChartCollection.Keys, ChartCollection.Values);
```

This works flawlessly.  I get my graph and a legend *made up of my foe names* and everything just fine.  But when I try to apply this code:

```
chtAgentVersions.Series[0].Label = "#VALX (#PERCENT)";
```

...the labels on my legend change from their appropriate foe names to zeroes.  Upon inspection of the Series after the databinding, I find that the names of my foes are actually not getting written to the XValues.  I even tried this:

```
chtAgentVersions.Series[0].XValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.String;
```

But, to no avail.  Why are they all zeroes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using strings as your `XValue`, use `#AXISLABEL` instead of `#VALX` since the `XValue` is always zero when used with strings.

Comment: Bah-zing, you got it.  I'll mark you as the answer in 9 minutes.  =)

Comment: Hey - i don't mean to bug you, but you don't have a good resource for the free-text dictionary associated with the Series object do you?  I can't find anything googling, and the key-value pairs are so esoteric I don't know where to begin...  This is what I'm talking about:  chtAgentVersions.Series[0]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Disabled";

Comment: There's a sample project with lots of samples regarding Charting controls. Here's the link: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart You can download and run the project to play with the rich set of properties....

Comment: Oh... I found the list with esoteric names hehehe =) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456764.aspx

Comment: You're the friggn' Sherlock Holmes of Microsoft Charts.  Thank you, sir.  =)